# L : X -> X, L linear, X normed space real space, then must L be continuous (even if the spaces X are infinite dimensional)?

Tags: functional-analysis

$L : X \rightarrow X$, $L$ linear, $X$ normed space real space, then can it be proven that $L$ must be continuous (even if the spaces $X$ are infinite dimensional)?

Comment: If $X$ is finite-dimensional, yes. Otherwise, $L$ may not be continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Simple example: Let $X$ be the space of all polynomials $P$, with the norm $$||P||=\sup_{0\le t\le 1}|P(t)|.$$ Define $T:X\to X$ by $TP=P'$, the derivative of $P$. Then $T$ is not continuous (because if $P_n(t)=t^n$ then $||TP_n||=n||P_n||$).

Answer (score 0):

Continuity is equivalent to boundedness and boundedness in finite dimensions is automatic. In infinite dimensions, there are very nice linear transformations that are not bounded. The prototypical example is constructed by picking a basis $(e_n)$ for the space (think of it as a generalization of the canonical basis from $\Bbb R^n$) and then defining $Te_n = n e_n$. This is not bounded and thus not continuous, but it is definitely linear!